# Как лучше хранить дату в БД?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, в каком формате лучше хранить дату в БД - в формате yyy-mm-dd или в формате unix?
И какой тип поля должен быть для unix - varchar?
Интересуют возможности дальнейшего оперирования датами.

Comment: > И какой тип поля должен быть для unix - varchar?

я, конечно, не очень знаком с MySQL но неужели в нем нет специальных типов для хранения дат наподобие datetime или date? Зачем все эти varchar?

Comment: В одном из ваших первых вопросов я показывал, как легко работать с datetime, можете попробовать сами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Я храню так:
```

- date тип: timestamp
- атрибуты: on update
- по умолчанию:   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Удобно обрабатывать.
получаемый формат: 2013-10-13 20:27:24

Comment: То есть timestamp сам переводит в секунды?

Comment: Для проектов, где возможно в минуту более одного действия (любого: добавление, редактирование, удаление статьи комментария, покупки),  по сути, это фиксация времени события, а вот показывать пользователю секунды, время или дату - решать тебе, тут всё есть.
____
Понял вопрос: да тут секунды привычные нам, время сервера (если погуглить, то можно найти указание временного пояса, нужного тебе).